# Use JHSDB to see where static variables are located

Tags: java, jvm

I encountered a problem while learning about the JVM
Code

```java
package chapter9;

public class JHSDBTest {
    static class Test{
        static ObjectHolder staticObj = new ObjectHolder();
        ObjectHolder instanceObj = new ObjectHolder();

        void foo(){
            ObjectHolder localObj = new ObjectHolder();
            //debug
            System.out.println("done");

        }
    }
    private static class ObjectHolder{}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Test test =  new JHSDBTest.Test();
       test.foo();
    }
}
```

After debugging, then use the jhsdb tool operation, follow the steps in the book step by step, but the result is not the same as the book.
This is what the book says
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R58iv.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3s3Ib.png)
This can not help but make me confused about the storage location of static variables, the book said that after jdk7 was moved out of the permanent generation, jdk8 after the meta-space replaced the permanent generation, but the storage of static variables is not included in the meta-space, so it is stored in the heap. I looked for a lot of posts, and many people said that I was a beginner in the method area, which confused me.

This is the result of my tool
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeEkm.png)
I am using jdk17, does anyone know why I did not find the expected static variable in the heap? It is worth mentioning that I have VM options configured.
Thanks to the big guy for the guidance.

Comment: You were looking for instances of the class `JHSDBTest$ObjectHolder` and got the error message "No such type." Indeed, there is no such class in your example, because your class belongs to the package `chapter9` and therefore its name is `chapter9.JHSDBTest$ObjectHolder`

Comment: I followed the steps in the book, but I ignored the package name until I saw your answer. The attempt according to your answer was successful, thank you very much。